# How to Update or Refresh the ViewModel Data and then the View

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm new to knockout and trying to figure out how to make it work for my current project.  Specifically, I have a viewmodel that is loaded with json data via an ajax call to the server.  Once the data is received, the knockout bindings are applied and the data is displayed  in the html on the screen.  Works good.

Now the difficult part... (at least for me)  Also, in the html, I have elements (checkboxes, radio buttons, dropdowns, etc.) in which the user can select values.  Once done selecting values, this user clicks a button to update the data on the page.  Thus, the button click sends the selected values back to the server to requery the database for a new collection of data.  The server then needs to send the updated list of json back to the page and knockout, and the viewmodel and the html display needs to be updated with the new data.  Or, at least this is how I need it to work.  I've been banging my head on how to do this for a while now.

So, after querying the database, binding knockout and the viewmodel, and displaying data, how can I request different data by requerying the database, get new data from the server, rebind knockout and the viewmodel to the new data, and display the new data in the same html page (just with the updated data)?????

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use model that represent your data within View Model and update this model instead of updating whole View Model

```
        function ViewModel()
        {
            this.data = ko.observable();
            var self = this;

            self.load = function()
            {
                var dataModel = new DataModel(1, 'Value');
                self.data(dataModel); // init
            };

            self.update = function()
            {
                var dataModel = new DataModel(2, 'Value UPD');
                self.data(dataModel); // update
            };
        }

        function DataModel(id, property)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.property = property;
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```